# Handle OAuth callback in node-webkit

Tags: node.js, github, oauth, github-api, node-webkit

I'm working on GitHub APIs and want to store returned `access_token` into `localStorage` in node-webkit.

So, the question is, how to fetch the token from a remote(HTTP) callback URL like `http://localhost:2222/github-callback?code=somecodehere`?

Answer (score 2):

Open authorization page in a new window

```
var authWindow = gui.Window.open("https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize");
```

Have a listener on its `loaded` event

```
authWindow.on('loaded', function() {
  if(authWindow.location.href.substr(0, 34) === "http://your.domain/github-callback") {
    // do what you want
  }
  // maybe some cleanup
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it already? the `authWindow.document.location.href.substr(0, 34)` wouldn't work.

Comment: This works but you need to use window instead of document: `authWindow.window.location.href`

Comment: @Kus Actually both are per specification(see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/Location)), but in this scene your way is more semantic, so yeah, I've fixed the answer.

Comment: @ZorcetaMoshak yes I'm aware its in the spec, but it doesn't actually work in node webkit when I tried it, where as window did.

Comment: @Kus haven't written node-webkit code for quite a while. Thanks for pointing out ;)